# id3lib linker error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code a program that can edit mp3 tag.
And now,I have a problem.
That is,when I compile,there is always errors.
and the error is Linker error.
Here is error descriptions:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall ID3_Tag::ID3_Tag(char const *)" (__imp_??0ID3_Tag@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _wmain 

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall ID3_Tag::~ID3_Tag(void)" (__imp_??1ID3_Tag@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
```

Does anyone know how or what to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't link against the appropriate libraries, where the symbols the linker is complaining about are exported.

[Here's how to link against the libs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/673730) which are probably found in [this archive](http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3lib/files/windows%20binaries/3.8.3/) (version number subject to change).

Comment: But I don't know how can I find the appropriate library.

Comment: @嘉豪許 please change your name so people can tag you - the libs should have been downloaded with the library - check the link I posted.

Comment: From the download it looks like id3lib.lib. However since this is a download from 2003 it may not work with a current compiler. You may have to build the library yourself. I recommend that because mixing libraries and dlls from different versions of Visual Studio can cause application crashes since there are differences in the Microsoft runtimes across versions.

Comment: I just download the link @LuchianGrigore post,and found the id3lib.lib.But can you tell me how to build the library by myself??

Comment: @sheu46 not really, because I've never done it, but it should be in the docs. However, if you already found the `lib` file, you shouldn't need to build it yourself, you just need to link against it (steps in the first link of my answer).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore ,I can't find the id3lib.lib file when I use my vs 2010,but I can find it when I use folder.

Comment: @sheu46 did you follow the exact steps? Did you add the path to the file to `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`?

Comment: Yes,I follow the step as you said~~

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Uhhh~~Just I can't find the lib file.

Comment: @sheu46 so that means you didn't add the folder correctly. That's the solution. That's what you have to do. It's clearly explained. There's no going around it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore add the folder correctly!?where should I put the folder I just downloaded that my visual studio 2010 can find it???

Comment: @sheu46 it's already explained in the answer. Go to project properties, navigate to the path I posted earlier, add the folder where the lib is there and the lib to `input->additional dependencies`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Thank you!!I just a little confused yet.But now I know what to do!Thx!